Apache Traffic Service - remap/redirect of HTTPS URLs
Playing with ATS as a forward proxy and wanting to block certain URL/FQDNs.  I have a remap config:
map https://bbc.co.uk/ https://www.google.co.uk/  
map https://www.bbc.co.uk/ https://www.google.co.uk/

It blocks the bbc.co.uk URL but doesn't do the remap/redirect.  We see a TCP_MISS/301, but never redirects and gets a ERR_PROXY_DENIED/403.
1720131982.447 0 80.101.137.52 TCP_MISS/301 544 CONNECT www.bbc.co.uk:443/ - DIRECT/- text/html
1720132076.578 0 80.101.137.52 ERR_PROXY_DENIED/403 419 CONNECT www.google.co.uk/ - NONE/- text/html

Any ideas?  Does a remap only work on HTTP?
